# PHP $_GET doesn't not work, but $_POST does

Tags: php, nginx, get

I try to `vardump($_GET)` or `print_r` it but it's empty every time.

I also use nginx as my webserver, and I route everything to index.php

I do that with this line in `nginx.conf`

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;`

Might that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was nginx's fault.
Fix it by editing the line to

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`

Comment: Just a note i couldn't notice` $query_string`, and i couldn't find it in the docs so i would suggest you check this https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#front-controller-pattern-web-apps

Comment: I use the latest latest nginx because I run a rolling release Linux distribution. It might be that it's a new option. It certainly works on my nginx server (version 1.19.9-1 as of this post)